# Python difflib: sequence similarity above cutoff point, but no result on get_close_matches()

Tags: python, python-3.x, difflib

So i'm using difflib to find same streets written down in different formats. Here's the one pair that really bugs me: '1-й Лихачевский переулок' and 'Переулок Лихачевский 1-й'.

I calculate the sequence similarity like this:

```
s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, "1-й Лихачевский переулок", "Переулок Лихачевский 1-й")
s.ratio()
```

Gives me result of 0.5416666666666666. Good enough, eh? But okay, default cutoff point for get_close_matches() is 0.6, so i do this:

```
difflib.get_close_matches('1-й Лихачевский переулок', 'Переулок Лихачевский 1-й', cutoff=0.5)
```

No results! In fact, there's no results even if i set cutoff to 0.1.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument to `get_close_matches()` is a sequence of strings to match against, not an individual string.  So, e.g., pass a list:

```
>>> difflib.get_close_matches('1-й Лихачевский переулок', ['Переулок Лихачевский 1-й'], cutoff=0.5)
['Переулок Лихачевский 1-й']
```

As is, you passed a string, which is treated as a sequence of individual characters.

Comment: Welp, that explains everything. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :-)  If your question has been answered, you should "accept" the answer you like best:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers